# Catmull-Rom Interpolator: Template pandemonium avoidance

Tags: c++, computational-geometry

I have a [pull request](https://github.com/boostorg/math/pull/95) implementing Catmull-Rom interpolation. I have gotten it pretty fast-to ~25 ns/call-but I feel the design is not enlightened. The code is [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/boostorg/math/577ee425a452587962226b201576a1e81404b532/include/boost/math/interpolators/catmull_rom.hpp), and reproduced below:

```
#ifndef BOOST_MATH_INTERPOLATORS_CATMULL_ROM
#define BOOST_MATH_INTERPOLATORS_CATMULL_ROM

#include <cmath>
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>

namespace boost{ namespace math{

    namespace detail
    {
        template<class Real, class Point, size_t dimension>
        Real alpha_distance(Point const & p1, Point const & p2, Real alpha)
        {
            using std::pow;
            Real dsq = 0;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < dimension; ++i)
            {
                Real dx = p1[i] - p2[i];
                dsq += dx*dx;
            }
            return pow(dsq, alpha/2);
        }
    }

template <class Real, class Point, size_t dimension>
class catmull_rom
{
public:

    catmull_rom(const Point* const points, size_t num_pnts, bool closed = false, Real alpha = (Real) 1/ (Real) 2);

    Real max_parameter() const
    {
        return m_max_s;
    }

    Real parameter_at_point(size_t i) const
    {
        return m_s[i+1];
    }

    Point operator()(Real s) const;


    Point prime(Real s) const;

private:
    std::vector<Point> m_pnts;
    std::vector<Real> m_s;
    Real m_max_s;
};

template<class Real, class Point, size_t dimension>
catmull_rom<Real, Point, dimension>::catmull_rom(const Point* const points, size_t num_pnts, bool closed, Real alpha)
{
    static_assert(dimension > 0, "The dimension of the Catmull-Rom spline must be > 0\n");
    if (num_pnts < 4)
    {
        throw std::domain_error("The Catmull-Rom curve requires at least 4 points.\n");
    }
    using std::abs;
    m_s.resize(num_pnts+3);
    m_pnts.resize(num_pnts+3);

    m_pnts[0] = points[num_pnts-1];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_pnts; ++i)
    {
        m_pnts[i+1] = points[i];
    }
    m_pnts[num_pnts+1] = points[0];
    m_pnts[num_pnts+2] = points[1];
    m_s[0] = -detail::alpha_distance<Real, Point, dimension>(m_pnts[0], m_pnts[1], alpha);
    if (abs(m_s[0]) < std::numeric_limits<Real>::epsilon())
    {
        throw std::domain_error("The first and last point should not be the same.\n");
    }
    m_s[1] = 0;
    for (size_t i = 2; i < m_s.size(); ++i)
    {
        Real d = detail::alpha_distance<Real, Point, dimension>(m_pnts[i], m_pnts[i-1], alpha);
        if (abs(d) < std::numeric_limits<Real>::epsilon())
        {
            throw std::domain_error("The control points of the Catmull-Rom curve are too close together; this will lead to ill-conditioning.\n");
        }
        m_s[i] = m_s[i-1] + d;
    }
    if(closed)
    {
        m_max_s = m_s[num_pnts+1];
    }
    else
    {
        m_max_s = m_s[num_pnts];
    }
}


template<class Real, class Point, size_t dimension>
Point catmull_rom<Real, Point, dimension>::operator()(Real s) const
{
    if (s < 0 || s > m_max_s)
    {
        throw std::domain_error("Parameter outside bounds.\n");
    }
    auto it = std::upper_bound(m_s.begin(), m_s.end(), s);
    //Now *it >= s. We want the index such that m_s[i] <= s < m_s[i+1]:
    size_t i = std::distance(m_s.begin(), it - 1);
    // We'll keep the assert in here a while until we feel good that we've understood this algorithm.
    //assert(m_s[i] <= s && s < m_s[i+1]);

    // Only denom21 is used twice:
    Real denom21 = 1/(m_s[i+1] - m_s[i]);
    Real s0s = m_s[i-1] - s;
    Real s1s = m_s[i] - s;
    Real s2s = m_s[i+1] - s;
    Real s3s = m_s[i+2] - s;

    Point A1_or_A3;
    Real denom = 1/(m_s[i] - m_s[i-1]);
    for(size_t j = 0; j < dimension; ++j)
    {
        A1_or_A3[j] = denom*(s1s*m_pnts[i-1][j] - s0s*m_pnts[i][j]);
    }

    Point A2_or_B2;
    for(size_t j = 0; j < dimension; ++j)
    {
        A2_or_B2[j] = denom21*(s2s*m_pnts[i][j] - s1s*m_pnts[i+1][j]);
    }

    Point B1_or_C;
    denom = 1/(m_s[i+1] - m_s[i-1]);
    for(size_t j = 0; j < dimension; ++j)
    {
        B1_or_C[j] = denom*(s2s*A1_or_A3[j] - s0s*A2_or_B2[j]);
    }

    denom = 1/(m_s[i+2] - m_s[i+1]);
    for(size_t j = 0; j < dimension; ++j)
    {
        A1_or_A3[j] = denom*(s3s*m_pnts[i+1][j] - s2s*m_pnts[i+2][j]);
    }

    Point B2;
    denom = 1/(m_s[i+2] - m_s[i]);
    for(size_t j = 0; j < dimension; ++j)
    {
        B2[j] = denom*(s3s*A2_or_B2[j] - s1s*A1_or_A3[j]);
    }

    for(size_t j = 0; j < dimension; ++j)
    {
        B1_or_C[j] = denom21*(s2s*B1_or_C[j] - s1s*B2[j]);
    }

    return B1_or_C;
}

template<class Real, class Point, size_t dimension>
Point catmull_rom<Real, Point, dimension>::prime(Real s) const
{
    // https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843595/how-can-i-calculate-the-derivative-of-a-catmull-rom-spline-with-nonuniform-param
    // http://denkovacs.com/2016/02/catmull-rom-spline-derivatives/
    if (s < 0 || s > m_max_s)
    {
        throw std::domain_error("Parameter outside bounds.\n");
    }
    auto it = std::upper_bound(m_s.begin(), m_s.end(), s);
    //Now *it >= s. We want the index such that m_s[i] <= s < m_s[i+1]:
    size_t i = std::distance(m_s.begin(), it - 1);
    // We'll keep the assert in here a while until we feel good that we've understood this algorithm.
    assert(m_s[i] <= s && s < m_s[i+1]);
    Point A1;
    Real denom = 1/(m_s[i] - m_s[i-1]);
    Real k1 = (m_s[i]-s)*denom;
    Real k2 = (s - m_s[i-1])*denom;
    for (size_t j = 0; j < dimension; ++j)
    {
        A1[j] = k1*m_pnts[i-1][j] + k2*m_pnts[i][j];
    }

    Point A1p;
    for (size_t j = 0; j < dimension; ++j)
    {
        A1p[j] = denom*(m_pnts[i][j] - m_pnts[i-1][j]);
    }

    Point A2;
    denom = 1/(m_s[i+1] - m_s[i]);
    k1 = (m_s[i+1]-s)*denom;
    k2 = (s - m_s[i])*denom;
    for (size_t j = 0; j < dimension; ++j)
    {
        A2[j] = k1*m_pnts[i][j] + k2*m_pnts[i+1][j];
    }

    Point A2p;
    for (size_t j = 0; j < dimension; ++j)
    {
        A2p[j] = denom*(m_pnts[i+1][j] - m_pnts[i][j]);
    }


    Point B1;
    for (size_t j = 0; j < dimension; ++j)
    {
        B1[j] = k1*A1[j] + k2*A2[j];
    }

    Point A3;
    denom = 1/(m_s[i+2] - m_s[i+1]);
    k1 = (m_s[i+2]-s)*denom;
    k2 = (s - m_s[i+1])*denom;
    for (size_t j = 0; j < dimension; ++j)
    {
        A3[j] = k1*m_pnts[i+1][j] + k2*m_pnts[i+2][j];
    }

    Point A3p;
    for (size_t j = 0; j < dimension; ++j)
    {
        A3p[j] = denom*(m_pnts[i+2][j] - m_pnts[i+1][j]);
    }

    Point B2;
    denom = 1/(m_s[i+2] - m_s[i]);
    k1 = (m_s[i+2]-s)*denom;
    k2 = (s - m_s[i])*denom;
    for (size_t j = 0; j < dimension; ++j)
    {
        B2[j] = k1*A2[j] + k2*A3[j];
    }

    Point B1p;
    denom = 1/(m_s[i+1] - m_s[i-1]);
    for (size_t j = 0; j < dimension; ++j)
    {
        B1p[j] = denom*(A2[j] - A1[j] + (m_s[i+1]- s)*A1p[j] + (s-m_s[i-1])*A2p[j]);
    }

    Point B2p;
    denom = 1/(m_s[i+2] - m_s[i]);
    for (size_t j = 0; j < dimension; ++j)
    {
        B2p[j] = denom*(A3[j] - A2[j] + (m_s[i+2] - s)*A2p[j] + (s - m_s[i])*A3p[j]);
    }

    Point Cp;
    denom = 1/(m_s[i+1] - m_s[i]);
    for (size_t j = 0; j < dimension; ++j)
    {
        Cp[j] = denom*(B2[j] - B1[j] + (m_s[i+1] - s)*B1p[j] + (s - m_s[i])*B2p[j]);
    }
    return Cp;
}


}}
#endif
```

The problems I have with this are as follows:

1. There are 3 template arguments: `Real`, `Point`, and `dimension`. However, suppose you choose the `Point` as a `std::array<Real, 3>`. Then the `Point` type already contains the information about the dimension and the type of the elements of the point. So in this case, the other two template arguments are redundant, making the code overly verbose. Is there any way to avoid this?
2. The `Point` type must allow subscripting, i.e., if `p` is of type `Point`, then `p[0]` must be defined and be of type `Real`. But this is a pretty drastic restriction, as (for example) boost.geometry point use `get<0>(p)` syntax to extract the `x` coordinate of the point, rather than subscript syntax. Is there any way around this?
3. I haven't written any webassembly before, but this seems to be a natural candidate to build into wasm. Is there any aspects of the current implementation that would make this impossible?

Comment: Is it tradition on this site to update the question to incorporate feedback as it comes in? @Toby Speight has solved problem 1 to my satisfaction.

Comment: No--especially once an answer has been posted, you should not make any changes that would render that answer obsolete.

Comment: See  [What should I do when someone answers my question?](/help/someone-answers) - especially the final section, *I improved my code based on the reviews. What next?*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a partial review, but:

- If `Point` is a Standard container, you can use its `size()` member function and `value_type` type to get the correct `dimension` and `Real`.  You'll want to check that `p1.size() == p2.size()` where appropriate, since they may now differ.
- If `Point` is not a Standard container, you could use free function `size()` after importing `std::size` into your scope; this allows you to provide an implementation for types that don't have it.  For element access, you may need to write an adapter that accepts standard containers but can be overloaded as appropriate for non-standard ones.

## Example (untested)

```
namespace detail
{
    template<class Point, class Real = typename Point::value_type>
    Real alpha_distance(Point const & p1, Point const & p2, Real alpha)
    {
        using std::pow;
        using std::size;
        Real dsq = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0;  i < size(p1) && i < size(p2);  ++i)
        {
            Real const dx = p1[i] - p2[i];
            dsq += dx*dx;
        }
        return pow(dsq, alpha/2);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `std::size` is a great simplification as it works for both `array` and `vector` types, though the C++17 might make some users angry. Tested the `class Real = typename Point::value_type` and it works and is a significant simplification. However, there's never a good reason to override the default argument, which might be a bit confusing.

Comment: Just found a workaround for the second issue: Replace `Real` by `typename Point::value_type` and everything is fine! Awesome suggestion.